# Why is the time taken by collections.Counter to construct a frequency map less than a simple dict creation by a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-collections

From what I understand, since `count()` iterates over the list again for each element it is slower. Since, the Counter and dict construction both iterate over the list once
shouldn't the dict construction and counter time results be similar?

I used the https://stackoverflow.com/a/23909767/7125235 as code reference for getting the time values.

```py
import timeit

if __name__ == "__main__":
    code_block = """seen = {}
for i in l:
    if seen.get(i):
        seen[i] += 1
    else:
        seen[i] = 1
"""
    setup = """import random
import string
from collections import Counter
n=1000
l=[random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(n)]
"""

    t1 = timeit.Timer(
        stmt="Counter(l)",
        setup=setup,
    )

    t2 = timeit.Timer(
        stmt="[[x,l.count(x)] for x in set(l)]",
        setup=setup,
    )
    t3 = timeit.Timer(
        stmt=code_block,
        setup=setup,
    )

    print("Counter(): ", t1.repeat(repeat=3, number=10000))
    print("count():   ", t2.repeat(repeat=3, number=10000))
    print("seen{}:   ", t3.repeat(repeat=3, number=10000))
```

Output:

Run1:

```
Counter():  [0.32974308, 0.319977907, 0.301750341]
count():    [6.424047524000001, 6.417152854, 6.450776530000001]
seen{}:    [1.1089669810000018, 1.099655232, 1.116015376]
```

Run 2:

```
Counter():  [0.322483783, 0.32464020800000004, 0.33498838900000005]
count():    [6.3235339029999995, 6.48233445, 6.543396192000001]
seen{}:    [1.1192663550000006, 1.1072084830000009, 1.1155270229999985]
```

Comment: Please be aware that ``timeit`` can also work with regular functions. There is no need to cram relevant parts of the question into such illegible strings.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Will take care in the future. I used the code snippet from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23909767/7125235

Comment: check your code. You first make a `set` out of the input list `l` in the `for` loop (effectively reducing the size). Your `dict` solution will not yield same result as `Counter` solution. Also I would run 3 alternatives with same input list.

Comment: @buran My bad, I changed the code to reflect the new times.

Comment: So, now you reversed the question?

Comment: Can you clarify your "new" question? The entire point of ``Counter`` is to count things. Why are you surprised that it is fast when counting thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

`Counter.__init__` is using a C loop (in CPython, at least) to count the iterable's elements, see https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6b1ac809b9718a369aea67b99077cdd682be2238/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L2277.

---

`Counter` is (mostly, see below) implemented in Python, meaning its code can be inspected, debugged and even modified very easily.

`Counter.__init__` in CPython 3.8 (docstring not included):

```
def __init__(self, iterable=None, /, **kwds):
    super(Counter, self).__init__()
    self.update(iterable, **kwds)
```

and `Counter.update` (irrelevant paths not included):

```
def update(self, iterable=None, /, **kwds):
    if iterable is not None:
        if isinstance(iterable, _collections_abc.Mapping):
            ...
        else:
            _count_elements(self, iterable)
    if kwds:
        ...
```

and `_count_elements`:

```
def _count_elements(mapping, iterable):
    mapping_get = mapping.get
    for elem in iterable:
        mapping[elem] = mapping_get(elem, 0) + 1
```

**However**, there is a very important piece of code + comment right below the implementation of `_count_elements`:

```
try:  # Load C helper function if available
    from _collections import _count_elements
except ImportError:
    pass
```

In other words, `Counter` uses a C loop to count the elements, which is inherently faster than the Python loop you are using.

We can do a small experiment. Comment out the code that imports the C function:

```
# try:   # Load C helper function if available
#     from _collections import _count_elements
# except ImportError:
#     pass
```

Executing your code:

```
Counter():  [1.8369901, 1.8359803000000001, 1.940804]
seen{}:    [1.2392313000000001, 1.2483893999999998, 1.3157528000000003]
```

Now `Counter` is actually slower than a plain dict.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your code to perform comparable operations on all three sections: import the same packages (to balance the overhead), and then search the entire list of characters, rather than reducing it to a unique string -- that was your main error in the "seen" code: you counted only one of each character.

```
import timeit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    code_block = '''seen = {}
for i in char:
    if seen.get(i):
        seen[i] += 1
    else:
        seen[i] = 1
'''

    common = 'import random;import string;from collections import Counter;n=1000;' + \
             'char=[random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(n)]'
    t1 = timeit.Timer(stmt='Counter(char)',
                      setup=common)

    t2 = timeit.Timer(stmt='[[x,char.count(x)] for x in set(char)]',
                      setup=common)
    t3 = timeit.Timer(stmt=code_block,
                      setup=common)

    print("Counter(): ", t1.repeat(repeat=3, number=10000))
    print("count():   ", t2.repeat(repeat=3, number=10000))
    print("seen{}:    ", t3.repeat(repeat=3, number=10000))
```

Output:

```
Counter():  [0.48620019999999997, 0.49807440000000014, 0.3896322000000001]
count():    [9.7432961, 9.620701299999999, 9.674791500000001]
seen{}:     [1.4734368999999994, 1.462895500000002, 1.4655799000000016]
```

It appears that `Counter` is, as expected, the fastest.

Comment: While you are at correcting the code: ``if seen.get(i):`` should likely just be ``if i in seen:``

Comment: `in` is my own preference, but not OP's.  The only non-functional correction I made was to replace `l` with `char`, since `l` is perhaps the worst variable name in existence: meaningless *and* hard to read.